# dynamically passing href in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, href, anchor

i want to redirect user to registration based on there role. like there is two roles user and shop if user select user role then it will be directed to the ragic.php(registration customer) if selected shop then ragis.php
Hear is the code...

```
 Link: `<td colspan=3 align="center"><font size=6 ><a onclick="return check_role()" href="" id="ref" name="Ragistration">Ragistration</a>`

Selecting Role: 

<select id="role" name="role">
                        <option value="ragic.php">user</option>
                        <option value="shop/ragis.php">shop</option>
                    </select>
Java Script Function :

 function check_role()
            {
                    var r=document.getElementById('role').value;
                    alert(r);
                    document.getElementById("ref").value = test;                    
            }
```

one problem is how i pass a javascript variable into anchor href. or i also try for php  hear is code

```
  if(@isset($Ragistration))
{
    if(@$role=="shop")
    $r="shop/ragis.php";
elseif(@$role=="user")
    $r="ragic.php";

}
```

and for php anchor tag will be `<a href="<?php echo $r?>" ></a>`

Comment: You don't need to pass anything into the link's href, inside your click handler you can simply use `location.href = ...` to navigate to the desired target URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your JavaScript function like this:

```js
function check_role()
{
  var r=document.getElementById('role').value;
  alert(r);
  location.href = r;
}
```